# how to dynamically add pic from array to src with v-bind in vue.js?

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I have some array with status and with pic. I woudlike to add the pic depending on the status.

I did this, and my pic href id adding to html, but I still dont see pic property.

HTML:

```
 .main_repayement
      .container
        .box(:class="boxBackground")
          .pic
          img(:src="putPicure")
```

VUE.JS

```
  computed: {
    status() {
     if (this.applicationData.confirmed == 0) {
      return 0;
     } else if (this.loan.data.delay > 0 && this.loan.data.debt > 0) {
       return 1;
     } else if (this.loan.data.debt > 0 && this.loan.data.delay == 0) {
       return 2;
     }
    return 0;
  },
   statusText() {
    let texts = [
    "wniosek w trakcie weryfikacji",
     "spłata opóźniona",
    "pożyczka aktywna"
  ];
  return texts[this.status];
  }
 putPicure() {
  let pic = [
    "@/../public/img/active.svg",
    "@/../public/img/delay.svg",
    "@/../public/img/ontime.svg"
  ];
  return pic[this.status];
},
  },
```

I think somethin is wrong with links? But Im not sure. Maybe sb can give me some advice.

**EDIT:**

I found my mistake. Like @Nina Lisitsinskaya wrote in the bottom, I had bad path. webpack is not handle with @. I changed my paths in array for like this:

```
putPicure() {
  let pic = ["/img/active.svg", "/img/delay.svg", "/img/ontime.svg"];
  return pic[this.status];
},
```

Now everything works perfect. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: try `img(:src="putPicure()")`

Comment: But this is not a function in methodes. It is in computed. Even this, it's still doesnt work.

Comment: Your JS is invalid because you do not have a comma before `putPicure()`.

Comment: I believe your logic is correct, but I don't think this is going to open, only if you have added a resolver for `public` folder. If you open in the browser the link generated in your image, is it work?

Comment: Also, is `@` a webpack alias for some path? Dynamically generated URLs are not processed by the webpack. So you should use full relative or absolute path of content to your web page.

Comment: When I changed the path (without @) the result is the same . I tried with many paths and it still doesn't work properly. So i thought my logic was incorrect.

Comment: When I add a one path to a HTML, no to an array it workes properly, with @. But when I put them to array, it crashed. So I suspect that the links are ok.